# Use more specificity when binding javascript to elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, dom-events

I have a situation where I am working on a large site and what I have been doing is using one main `.js` file to store all my bound js code that I want to use on elements such as onclick, onchange etc etc.... these are all held within the one `onDomReady` method.

Now I'm wondering is it such a good idea to have each page have to go over these and "search" for each element to see if it has to bind anything?

..or should I perhaps use more specificity to prevent this such as the main page ID like `#page1`, `#page2` etc OR should I store these in the specifics pages header (I don't really want to do that as I prefer to keep it all in one place).

Just trying to optimize things and get rid of unnecessary overhead! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you have one js file with all your event handlers.
This file is included i many pages.

So for example, if there are 100 event handlers in the file, each page may be using only 10 of these.

If thats the case, then its not efficinet, because you have lots of 
document.getElementBy...  that are not fnding the elements, because they belong to a different page, or worse, finding elements with same selector on multile pages that should not be binded to handlers on a specific page.

also, you are adding script to a page that it does not need.

Best to give each page only what it needs, be it in external js or if very little script, in doucment head.

js that you share across pages should be code that you intend to re-use often.

EDIT: 
In response to comment:

regarding reducing http requests, you mean the one file will be in cache, for other pages to use? fair enough, that counts as a benefit. Though there are tradeoffs, such as increased memory usage due to javascript that you dont need in page.

using more specific selector will reduce the risk of attaching event handler to wrong element in a page that you did not mean to target, but there is a safer option:

If you insit on sharing one event handler file across pages,
Group them by wrapping them a function, one for each page. call that function from the page.

This way, you dont have to execute a bunch of code that you dont need, and don't risk adding wrong event handlers to simmilar elements accross pages.

Comment: Yeah... you understood well enough; though I am using jQuery. Wouldn't using more `specificity` help though? Also, I try and not use extra `.js` files because I like to keep the number of http requests down as much as possible.

Comment: Not a bad idea, so basically group all the page JS code in separate functions and then call the respective function in the head of each separate page?

Comment: yes. Also, if you wish, you could implement some generic solution, using a system such as :  {'pageID1' : eventHandlerFunc1, 'pageID2': eventHandlerFunc2} then,you dont need to call eventHandlerFunc1 in head of page1 and eventHandlerFunc2 in head of page2. you could, in the same global js file, call a function that reads pageID from data attribute on page, and executes the corresponding eventHandlerFunc for that page. the drawback is that its a bit less efficient than from head of page, and increases complexity.

Comment: Yeah, true. Well thanks for ideas; I'll end up using one of them :)